# C# - Join Syntax with two tables

Tags: c#, linq

I have an app built with C#. This app uses Entity Framework to query tables. In my databsae, I have two tables:

```
Department
----------
Id
Name
RemovedOn

Managers
---------
Id
Name
DepartmentId
```

When a user accesses the page, I have their ID. I need to get all of the departments associated with that manager. Currently, I have the following:

```
var managerDepartments = MyDb.Departments
  .Where(d => d.RemovedOn == null)
  .OrderBy(d => d.Name)
  .ToList();
```

This gives me all departments. However, it doesn't give me the list of departments specific to the manager. I know I can get the manager using something like this:

```
var manager = MyDb.Managers
  .Where(m => m.Id == this.CurrentUserId)
  .FirstOrDefault();
```

However, this doesn't bridge the two. I know I need to do a join. However, I don't know what that syntax looks like. Can someone please show me how to get all of the departments for a manager?

Thank you

Comment: Why are you using joins instead of defining relations and navigation properties between the entities? You could write `someManager.Department` and retrieve the department without joining. If you have to join in code, why use an ORM at all?

Comment: Not my downvote btw. This *is* a bug though